# Find duplicate values in an arraylist without using LINQ

Tags: c#-2.0, arraylist, duplicates

I have an arraylist with few duplicate items. I need to know the count of each duplicated item. I am using 2.0 so cannot use linq.

I had posted a similar question earlier, but my question was not clear.
Thanks
Prady

Comment: Why did you tag it C#-3.0 if you are using 2.0?

Comment: sorry, i was changing it and you commented on it

Comment: Why would you use ArrayList in 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something in the past.  My solution was to loop through the ArrayList and store the counts in a dictionary.  Then loop though the dictionary to display the results:

```
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add("test");
        list.Add("test");
        list.Add("test");
        list.Add(2);
        list.Add(3);
        list.Add(2);

        Dictionary<Object, int> itemCount = new Dictionary<object, int>();

        foreach (object o in list)
        {
            if (itemCount.ContainsKey(o))
                itemCount[o]++;
            else
                itemCount.Add(o, 1);
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Object, int> item in itemCount)
        {
            if (item.Value > 1)
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " count: " + item.Value);
        }
```

Output:

```
test count: 3
2 count: 2
```

**Edit**
Realized I used the var keyword which is not a 2.0 feature.  Replaced it with KeyValuePair.

Comment: Thanks Chris... just one question though.. is there any way i can get to know the no of counts if i know the keyvalue. For instance i want to know the count of test, using something like find(test) will return 3

Comment: Yup.  Using the code above.  If you wanted to know the count of 2 you'd just do something like 'int count = itemCount[2]'.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: Sort the list and then count adjacently Equal items (requires you to override the Equals method for your class)

**Option 2**: Use your unique identifier (however you're defining two objects to be equal) as the key for a Dictionary and add each of your objects to that entry.

Answer (score 0):

i needed something similar for a project a long time ago, and made a function for it

```
    static Dictionary<object, int> GetDuplicates(ArrayList list, out ArrayList uniqueList)
    {
        uniqueList = new ArrayList();
        Dictionary<object, int> dups = new Dictionary<object, int>();
        foreach (object o in list)
        {
            if (uniqueList.Contains(o))
                if (!dups.ContainsKey(o))
                    dups.Add(o, 2);
                else
                    dups[o]++;
            else
                uniqueList.Add(o);
        }
        return dups;
    }
```